# manifest vs show/express

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, word-meaning

I wrote a sentence:

Vietnamese culture **manifests** the unity of a multi-ethnic national culture and is against cultural racism and forced acculturation of one ethnic group by another.

At the beginning, I chose **express/show** instead of **manifest** because I feel like manifest is a specific type of **express/show**. Therefore, I should use **express/show** to ensure the meaning. However, I tried looking up in the dictionary and found a bunch of definitions that in my opinion don't fit this context

Then, I tried to look up manifest
Manifest: to show something clearly, especially a feeling, an attitude or a quality
--> so basically **manifest** is used to **show/express** an abstract thing; therefore,  is what I understood correct? or in this case should I just stick to **show/express**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest suits perfectly in your example. There are also other synonyms that can fit in your sentence.

For example:

> Vietnamese culture **[*manifests* / *demonstrates* / *reveals* / *indicates* / *betrays*]** the unity of a multi-ethnic national culture and is against cultural racism and forced acculturation of one ethnic group by another.